# Numpy: Indices of multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, indices

I would like to set some values of a 2D array to a specific number by indexing them efficiently.

Say I have a 2D numpy array,

```
A = array([[1, 6, 6],
           [9, 7, 7], 
           [10, 2, 2]])
```

and I would like to get the indices in the array that belong to a set of numbers, say `indList=[10, 1]` so that I can set them to zero. However, `indList` can be a huge list.

Is there a faster way for doing this without a for loop?

As a for loop it would be,

```
indList = [10, 1]
for i in indList:
    A[A==i] = 0
```

But this can get inefficient when `indList` is large.

Comment: You are right, that looked weird... fixed it, it is a `3x3` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With numpy, you can vectorize this by first finding the indices of elements that are in `indList` and then setting them to be zero.

```
A = np.array([[1, 6, 6],
              [9, 7, 7],
              [10 ,2 ,2]])

A[np.where(np.isin(A, [10,1]))] = 0
```

This gives

```
A = [[0 6 6]
     [9 7 7]
     [0 2 2]]
```

Comment: it seems that `np.isin` is very slow, is there a reason why it is much slower than doing A==10 for example?

Answer (score 2):

From @Miket25's answer, there is actually no need to add the `np.where` layer. `np.isin(A, [10, 1])` returns a boolean array which is perfectly acceptable as an index. So simply do

```
A[np.isin(A, [10, 1])] = 0
```